# How to Scroll Draw only for the length of a div?

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll, draw

Hi I'm looking at the Scroll Drawing examples over on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scrolldrawing.asp) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-drawing/). Both examples use Javascript and an SVG path to "draw" an element on scroll. They also both base the length of the drawn path according to how much the document body has been scrolled (scroll percentage). Here's how they calculate their scroll percentage:

```
var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

Does anyone know how I can change the scroll percentage so that it calculates based on how far down a div has been scrolled?

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anelec/5ej8hqtg/7/#&togetherjs=BT6cTkPju2) where I tried using the y of the div's boundingClientRect() divided by the window.innerHeight. This probably doesn't make sense because it seems to be drawn over and over again, but I'm trying to figure out the math. The SVG in this case is sticky to the div (instead of fixed). This only kind of works in that the SVG path is drawn on scroll, but it's drawn over and over again until you've scrolled past the height of the div.

My desired outcome is for it to be drawn once completely when scrolled 50% down the div and stay drawn for scrolling the remaining 50% of the div.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help in advance! Any references would help too in terms of JS math and logic!

Also, for the SVG itself, do you know which end of the path is the one that starts?

Comment: okay here's a [version](https://jsfiddle.net/anelec/txqnermj/14/) that's working better in that the shape is drawn only once, but the drawing goes offscreen before complete.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured this out. Here's the complete [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anelec/aLn4qteo/13/)

The math for calculating the scroll percentage: get the amount that the window has scrolled and divide by the height of the div (that the SVG is in). You then want to divide this in half so that the drawing completes halfway before div finishes scrolling:

```
var svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container");
var svgContainerRect = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
var svgDivHeight = svgContainerRect.height;
var windowScroll = window.pageYOffset;

var scrollPercent = windowScroll / svgDivHeight *2;
```

Then, for the drawing to remain "drawn" after scrolling halfway through the div, throw the "drawing function" into an "if". This stops drawing once the scroll percentage reaches 1 (reaching halfway down the page):

```
if (scrollPercent < 1) {

  //draw the length of SVG path according to the scroll
  var draw = length * scrollPercent;
  // Reverse the drawing (when scrolling upwards)
  triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;

} else {
    var still = length;
}
```

The only quirk is that when the drawing is reversed (when you scroll up and then scroll back down), it seems to not complete all the way, like there's a bit of length missing. More to figure out, but the main function is there.

I guess it just took me a while to figure out the simple math. Hope this can help someone in the future.